# How do I pull data from the my database using a php function

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I have in my main page:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$strQry=$foo->Client();
$user_data=mysql_fetch_object($user_res);
echo $user_data->clientid;
```

This is what I have in my class file:

```
class Foo
{
function Client() 
{
$strQry = "SELECT clientid FROM users";
$user_res = mysql_query($strQry) or die("Unable to select, Error: ".mysql_error());
return $user_res;
}
}
```

I am not very good at using classes and functions with PHP and so I'm getting this error "Unable to select, Error: Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you connect to the database?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not even making a connection to the database.

Here's a nice step-by-step walk through, that should show you how to connect to a mysql database using either mysqli or pdo, which are both more safe ways to talk to mysql.

http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 2):

There a a number of issues with your code:

- You should not be using `mysql_*` functions.  They are deprecated.  If you are just learning about using PHP with databases, do it the right way and use `mysqli` or `PDO`.
- You need to make sure you are actually connecting to the database.  Maybe you are and it is not shown here, but this is obviously critical.
- You are intending to return a database result from your `Client()` method call. But you are not using the variable your returned the results into.

This code:

```
$strQry=$foo->Client();
$user_data=mysql_fetch_object($user_res);
```

Should be:

```
$strQry=$foo->Client();
$user_data=mysql_fetch_object($strQry);
```

because `$strQry` gets the result set resource.

- You are only calling `mysql_fetch_object()` once.  You could have any number of rows in the result set based on your query.  If you want all of them, you would need to loop through the result set and call `mysql_fetch_object()` on each row.

Perhaps something like this:

```
$user_data= array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($strQry)) {
    $user_data[] = $row;
}
```

- If you INSIST on using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, you might at least want to get in the habit of passing the DB connection as a parameter in your functions, to make it clear which DB connection you are working with.

So do something like:

```
mysql_query($strQry, $dbConn);
```